# HttpPost send GET to the server

Tags: java, android, http-post

Problem on my part is solved
The owner of the server removed some code to check if the basics of sending a POST/GET method works and that works perfectly.

I'm still dont know what the problem is, but it sure is not my problem lol

---

I'm trying to send `POST` method to the server, but it turns out the server gets a `GET` method instead. We got it working on the iphone so the server is correct.

This is the code I written to send data:

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://myurl.nl/casus");
    httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        //casus
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("casusid", casus.id+""));

        String woorden = "[";
        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
            woorden += "\""+words[i]+"\"";
            if(i != words.length-1){
                woorden += ",";
            }
        }
        woorden += "]";
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("woorden", woorden));
        //info
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("omapp", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String age = sharedPref.getString("age", "");
        String sex = sharedPref.getString("sex", "");
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("leeftijdscategorie", age));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("geslacht", sex));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Log.d("json", responseBody);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

PHP code:

```
    // Service token authorization.
    require_once('../classlib/Auth.php');
    $auth = new Auth;
    if ( !$auth->valid() ) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
        exit;
    }

    // Setup casussen.
    require_once('../classlib/PDOFactory.php');
    require_once('../classlib/Casussen.php');
    $casussen = new Casussen;
    $casussen->setPDO(PDOFactory::create());

    $rs = (object) array();
    switch ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {

        case 'GET': {
            mail('sdgsdgsdg@gmail.com', 'The get method was called', print_r($_SERVER,1));
            $fromcasusid = !empty($_GET['fromcasusid']) ? (int) $_GET['fromcasusid'] : null;
            $rs->casussen =$casussen->get($fromcasusid);
            break;
        }

        case 'POST': {
            mail('jsdgsdgsn@gmail.com', 'The post method was called', print_r($_SERVER,1));
            $casusreactie = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
            try {
                $casussen->post($casusreactie);
            } catch ( Exception $e ) {
                $rs->error = (object) array(
                    'code' => $e->getCode(),
                    'message' => $e->getMessage(),
                );
            }
            break;
        }

        default: {
            header('HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed');
            exit;
        }

    } // switch

    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    exit(json_encode($rs));
```

Comment: as far as I see, your code looks correct. maybe there is a problem on the server?

Comment: @Jaytjuh: Can you paste your server side code?

Comment: I dont think so cause on the iphone when sending a POST method, the server does receive a POST method.

Comment: got the php code :) Ill edit my post

Comment: is there any redirection rule somewhere in the middle (i.e. in your web server configuration ? it is possible that this rule, if it exists don't apply to request comming from iPhone - because a guard based on useragent for instance)

Comment: What do you mean? I in the information that is mailed to me that iphone has  [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Om%20EIS/1.0 CFNetwork/609.1.4 Darwin/13.0.0   and android doest has http_user_agent

Comment: the owner of the server tells me there's no redirections

Comment: It turns out the server doesnt get ANY atributes from the app....

Answer (score 0):

One workout..

call doPost method from inside your doGet

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException{

doPOst(request, response)
}
```

Comment: he didnt know cause the php code was later added to my question

Answer (score 0):

I was also having a similar issues. 
I was able to fix it by add "www." to the url.
But i would like to know how that is making a difference, I had successfully tested the server handling with a jQuery ajax request without the "www." .